# Build and manipulate array based on required fields populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, required, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm trying to figure out a sensible way to display and manipulate an array/list of required fields which are yet to be populated in a form - this is just so i can output this info to the user and remove each item from the list as the user goes through and populates the fields (as a sort of progress indicator). Any thoughts on how best to handle this?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of the following:

```
var reqFields = [];

jQuery('label.required').each(function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this).text());

    reqFields.push(jQuery(this).text());
});

jQuery('.custom-field').on('input', function() {
    if (jQuery('.required-entry').filter(function() {
            return this.value.length === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
        // Remove this from the list/array
    } else {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On input event check the value and accordingly add/remove item in array.

```
var reqFields = [];

jQuery('label.required').each(function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this).text());
    reqFields.push(jQuery(this).text());
});

jQuery('.custom-field').on('input', function() {
    if (this.value) {
        // Remove this from the list/array
        reqFields.splice(jQuery(this).index(),1);
        // jQuery(this).index() havent tried, else just compute index some other way
    } else {
       // add back if cleared out
       reqFields.push( jQuery('label.required').eq(jQuery(this).index()).text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the entries, every time there's a change in input of the required fields, you can simply re-assign the `reqFields` array to the list of required fields with empty input.

```
var reqFields = [];

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.requiredFields').on('input', function() {
    reqFields = jQuery('.requiredFields').filter(function() {
      return this.value.length === 0;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this basic example bellow using `each` on `input` to loop through all the fields with class `required-entry` and check the empty ones to finally append message to span `#msg` to inform the user which fields are required.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.required-entry').on('input', function() {
    $('#msg').empty();
  
    $('.required-entry').each(function() {
         if ( $(this).val().length == 0 )
             $('#msg').append('Field <b>'+$(this).prev('label').text()+'</b> is required.<br/>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='required'>First Name</label>
<input type='text' id='first_name' name='first_name' class='required-entry' required/>
<br/>
<label class='required'>Last Name</label>
<input type='text' id='last_name' name='last_name' class='required-entry' required/>
<br/>
<label class='required'>Email Address</label>
<input type='text' id='email' name='email' class='required-entry' required/>
<hr/>
<br/>
<span id='msg'></span>
```